# How to make all numbers and letter take up the same amount of space in latex?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to show step by step how to sort an array. But since the numbers and letters take up different amounts of space, the columns get staggered. I'm very new to latex and am not sure if there's an easy fix for this.

If that's not possible, is there some kind of grid system I can use to keep them in straight lines? (without showing the grid).

Comment: Unless you want a particular font, you could just switch to a mono spaced font.

Comment: You can use a table. Tabular environment is the usual way to get alignment. But you should you your present latex code and results, so that people can give you the right answer.

Comment: @AlainMerigot Tables work perfectly. Exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can place each of the elements in a box that are of similar width and height. This will ensure that each take up the same amount of space. It's possible using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`. All `\eqmakebox`es with the same `<tag>` are put in a box of maximum width of `<stuff>`. You can adjust the `<align>`ment of every element, if needed (`c`entred, `l`eft-aligned or `r`ight-aligned).

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\swl}[2][nmbr]{\eqmakebox[#1]{\strut #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \swl{a}\swl{b}\swl{m}\swl{0} \\
  \swl{i}\swl{i}\swl{1}\swl{n}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The above code provides a wrapper `\swl[<tag>]{<stuff>}` that provides a `s`imilar-`w`idth `l`etter macro. If you want a blank space, you can use `\swl{~}`.

`eqparbox` uses TeX's `\label`-`\ref` system to store the widths and therefore requires at least two compilations for any change (increase in width) in elements under the same `<tag>`.